# set notification alert every 24 hours android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to fire a local notification every 24 hours at a specific time say evening 6 o clock

i have refered this code

[here](http://www.banane.com/2014/05/07/simple-example-of-scheduled-self-clearing-android-notifications/)

and

[here](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/)

This is the code i am trying

```
package com.banane.alarm;

import java.util.Calendar;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "BANANEALARM";
    public AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Intent alarmIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Button bananaButton;
    TextView notificationCount;
    TextView notificationCountLabel;
    int mNotificationCount;
    static final String NOTIFICATION_COUNT = "notificationCount";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            mNotificationCount = savedInstanceState.getInt(NOTIFICATION_COUNT);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bananaButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bananaButton);
        notificationCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notificationCount);
        notificationCountLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notificationCountLabel);

    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putInt(NOTIFICATION_COUNT, mNotificationCount);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

     @Override
     protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent ) {
         Log.i( TAG, "onNewIntent(), intent = " + intent );
            if (intent.getExtras() != null)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "in onNewIntent = " + intent.getExtras().getString("test"));
            }
            super.onNewIntent( intent );
            setIntent( intent );
      }


    public void triggerAlarm(View v){
        setAlarm();
        bananaButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        notificationCountLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notificationCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notificationCount.setText("0");
    }

    public void setAlarm(){
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 18); // At the hour you wanna fire
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00); // Particular minute
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    //  alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), getInterval(), pendingIntent);
        //Log.i(TAG,"Alarms set every two minutes.");

    }

    private int getInterval(){
        int seconds = 60;
        int milliseconds = 1000;
        int repeatMS = seconds * 1440 * milliseconds;
        return repeatMS;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        updateUI();
    }

    public void cancelNotifications(){
        Log.i(TAG,"All notifications cancelled.");
    }

    public void updateUI(){
        MyAlarm app = (MyAlarm)getApplicationContext();
        mNotificationCount = app.getNotificationCount();
        notificationCount.setText(Integer.toString(mNotificationCount));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(this.getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            Log.i(TAG,"extras: " + this.getIntent().getExtras());
            updateUI();

        }
     }

   }
```

when try the code given in the example it works perfectly hwoever when i try to fire a notification i just wont show up what error

Comment: set alarm for next 24 hour when notification shows up.

Comment: well i came to know the real issue the alarm triggers at 6 am instead of 1800 as stated in the code now i am struggling to set the alarm at 6 pm in evening

Comment: Use HOUR_OF_DAY for 24hour format. To set alarm after next 12 hour set, calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);.

Comment: Try every few minutes first, get the notification working (see commented out code), then figure out the time zone issue.